# How to have a user control within MainForm call the MainForm Objects?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, user-controls

I have a user control that I created with certain buttons, and I placed it within the main form, which already contains things like buttons and panels. I want to control(send messages) to these fields when I press the buttons in the user control, but I can't figure out the OOP implementation required to achieve this.

I was advised to create an Initialize(f as Mainform) in the user control code in order to keep an explicit reference to the main form, but I have not been able to control the fields of the main form.

How can this be achieved? I am using visual basic, btw.

Comment: You already know how a button and a panel do it.  They generate an event and you write an event handler in your Form class.  Just do that in your UserControl as well.  Use the `Event` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Declare an event in the user control, and then write a handler for that event in the form.

In the control:

```
Event Zoomed()
```

In the control, to raise the event (call the handler):

```
RaiseEvent Zoomed()
```

and add the handler to the form:

```
Sub aview_zoomed() Handles aView.Zoomed
...
End Sub
```